# How do I Open Windows Registry with write access in Python

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7, registry, access-denied, winreg

I'm having some problems accessing the Windows 7 Registry with the [_winreg.QueryValueEx](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.QueryValueEx)  function in the Python 2.7.3 [_winreg](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) module.

I am running the python process as **Administrator**, and can create new keys and values like this:

```
import _winreg as wreg
key = wreg.CreateKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject")
# Create new subkey
wreg.SetValue(key, 'NewSubkey', wreg.REG_SZ, 'testsubkey')
print wreg.QueryValue(key, 'NewSubKey')
# prints 'testsubkey'
# Create new value
wreg.SetValueEx(key, 'ValueName', 0, wreg.REG_SZ, 'testvalue')
print wreg.QueryValueEx(key,'ValueName')
# prints (u'testvalue', 1)
key.Close()
```

[image: Keys in Windows Registry]

However, when I re-open the same key and try to set the value, it gives me an `Access is denied` error:

```
key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject",wreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
wreg.SetValue(key, 'NewSubkey', wreg.REG_SZ, 'subkey_changed')
print wreg.QueryValue(key, 'NewSubkey')
# prints 'subkey_changed'
wreg.SetValueEx(key, 'ValueName', 0, wreg.REG_SZ, 'value_changed')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    wreg.SetValueEx(key, 'ValueName', 0, wreg.REG_SZ, 'value_changed')
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

print wreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'ValueName')
# still prints: (u'testvalue', 1)
key.Close()
```

Interestingly, running as **Administrator**, I cannot open with [KEY_WRITE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.KEY_WRITE) or [KEY_ALL_ACCESS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) access rights:

```
>>> key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject",wreg.KEY_WRITE)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject",wreg.KEY_WRITE)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
>>> key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject",wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject",wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know how to CreateKey without admin privileges.

Comment: @macdonjo: I think you can't do this with HKLM due to security constraints, but you may be able to write to certain keys under HKCU (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing CURRENT_USER instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing:

```
key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject",0, wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!  This had been bugging me for a while.  I found that I had overlooked this in the documentation for [_winreg.OpenKey()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.OpenKey).  The part I missed was `_winreg.OpenKey(key, sub_key[, res[, sam]])` **...** `res is a reserved integer, and must be zero. The default is zero.`