# Access is denied in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, winreg

I am wanting to add a registry key with python via this code:

```
import _winreg
from time import sleep
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,'Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run',_winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
_winreg.SetValueEx(key,'Windows-Update',0,_winreg.REG_BINARY,'C:\Windows\System32\SystemSetting\Block.exe') 
key.Close()
```

But it shows up this error `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`.

Any solution?

EDIT - I have already run it as admin

EDIT2 - Is it related to `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`

Comment: Run Python interpreter as admin.

Comment: @Rogalski Already done

Comment: Shouldn't the path string be `'C:\\Windows\\System32\\SystemSetting\\Block.exe'`?

Comment: @martineau You don't need that while adding to registry as if you put double `\\ ` then the actual path would also change with double `\\`

Comment: If you're running the 32-bit Python interpreter on 64-bit Windows OS, the issue may something to do with to way the [WoW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system) subsystem handles interactions with the Windows Registry.

Comment: @martineau Yes I know that but that is not a issue, that is an excellent solution to 32bit and 64bit related issues

Comment: I think you may be wrong about not needing the double backslashes — because the handling of backslashes in string literals is hardcoded into the Python interpreter.

Comment: @martineau No. I went to regedit after running the script and the path was correct

Comment: How could that be if the script isn't working? What line is giving you the `WindowsError`?

Comment: @martineau After I ran it CORRECTLY as administartor which I wasn't doing then, it gave me the correct path

Comment: Related: [How to avoid “WindowsError: \[Error 5\] Access is denied”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37830326/3357935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the python program inside command prompt. There is a `command prompt (Admin)` program available in windows. Or simply right click on `Command prompt` and select `Run as administrator`. [Ref](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: what python program? the script?

Comment: yup, store the program as a py file and run it in command prompt.

Comment: As a sidenote I will be compiling this script and distributing it. So I think the `Run as Admin` option after right clicking will be sufficient. Right?

Comment: It depends upon the machine, so you have to test it in different machines to verify.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about runnig as admin. I tried runnig as admin and still got `Acces is denied` message.

You must use reserved integer which is 0 by default.

> _winreg.OpenKey(key, sub_key[, res[, sam]]) ... res is a reserved integer, and must be zero. The default is zero.

So, it should be like this:

```
key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\TestCompany\\TestProject",0, wreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
```

You don't realy have to use `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030033/how-do-i-open-windows-registry-with-write-access-in-python). Just add that `0` before `_winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE`.