# Access denied to open the registry

Tags: python, windows, registry

Every time I try to modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"` with Python I get the response 'access denied'.

Is there any solution to modify this registry programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030033/how-do-i-open-windows-registry-with-write-access-in-python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question details. In particular, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us understand what you've tried.